# Why is this program ignoring the Values field?

Tags: vb.net

```
Structure WeightElement
    Dim LowPointer As Integer
    Dim HighPointer As Integer
    Dim TraitPointer As Integer
    Dim Values As WeightedTrait()
    Dim Num As Integer
End Structure
Structure WeightedTrait
    Dim TraitName As String
    Dim TraitNum As Integer
    Dim WeightValue As Decimal
End Structure
Function DefaultWeights()
    Dim Weight(39) As WeightElement
    Weight(0).LowPointer = 1
    Weight(0).HighPointer = 2
    Weight(0).Num = 5
    Weight(0).Values = DefaultValues({"Black", "White", "East Asian", "South Asian", "Middle Eastern"}, {26, 30, 27, 28, 29})
    Return Weight
End Function
Function DefaultValues(NameArray() As String, NumArray() As Integer)
    Dim Weight(NameArray.Length) As WeightedTrait
    For x = 0 To NameArray.Length - 1
        Weight(x).TraitName = NameArray(x)
        Weight(x).TraitNum = NumArray(x)
        Weight(x).WeightValue = 1
    Next
    Return Weight
End Function
Sub Main()
    Dim Query As String = ""
    Dim Weight() As WeightElement = DefaultWeights()
    For x = 0 To 38
        Query += Str(Weight(x).LowPointer)
        Query += ","
        Query += Str(Weight(x).HighPointer)
        Query += ","
        Query += Str(Weight(x).TraitPointer)
        Query += ","
        Query += Str(Weight(x).Num)
        Query += ","
        Try
            For y = 0 To Weight(x).Values.Length - 1
                Query += Str(Weight(x).Values(y).TraitName)
                Query += ","
                Query += Str(Weight(x).Values(y).TraitNum)
                Query += ","
                Query += Str(Weight(x).Values(y).WeightValue)
                Query += ","
            Next
        Catch
            Query += "FLOCK"
        End Try
        Query += ";"
    Next
    Console.WriteLine(Query)
End Sub
```

The code is supposed to transform a weight into a string, yet when I run it the values in the Values array in the weight is nowhere to be seen. Instead, for some reason it decides to always go down the catch statement, and append that instead. Why won't it acknowledge the Values array?

Comment: It might be instructional to comment out the Catch and see what error message it gives you.

Comment: Instead of `Str`, you should use `.ToString()`, for example: `Query += Weight(x).LowPointer.ToString()`. However, if you use the VB.NET string concatenation operator, which is `&`, that does a .ToString() on its arguments for you, so you could write `Query &= Weight(x).LowPointer`.

Comment: You'll find that Visual Studio can spot a lot of programming problems and suggest solutions to you if you set [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) for this project. It's a good idea to set it as the default for new projects too (the instructions for that are also in the linked article).

Comment: A word to the wise: Avoid mutable `Structure`s at all costs.  It is extremely difficult to reason about when the language will make copies (so that your changes don't persist).  I would **strongly** recommend converting `WeightElement` and `WeightedTrait` to `Class`, and see if your problem persists.

Comment: By "mutable `Structure`" I mean any `Structure` that has anything other than `ReadOnly` properties as part of its public interface.

Comment: If you run in Visual Studio, you will be able to see the error on the line: For y = 0 To Weight(x).Values.Length - 1 before the Catch handles it.
The problem is that you are only initially setting Weight(0).Values and the Main code is looping through 39 items. Weight(1).Values = Nothing and so forth.
Looking at the output, it shows the DefaultWeights you set for Weight(0) but the 38 other items after that have 0 values which of course is the default for the Integer properties in the struct and so don't raise an error.

Answer (score 0):

DefaultWeights() only initializes one WeightElement so only Weight(0).Values is set. Weight(1).Values to Weight(39).Values remain set to Nothing so the Length property is not available and an error is raised.
Note that the most accurate way to find the upper bound of an array is to use the GetUpperBound function. For one-dimensional arrays, the dimension parameter = 0.In this case, the array has been created with the upper bound set to 39 (room for 40 elements). If this size was changed, the Main code would not need to be updated with the new size. 
I have also modified the code to only output the Query string if Weight(x).Values has been populated.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim Query As String = ""
    Dim Weight() As WeightElement = DefaultWeights()
    For x = 0 To Weight.GetUpperBound(0)
        Try
            If Weight(x).Values IsNot Nothing Then
                Query += CStr(Weight(x).LowPointer)
                Query += ","
                Query += CStr(Weight(x).HighPointer)
                Query += ","
                Query += CStr(Weight(x).TraitPointer)
                Query += ","
                Query += CStr(Weight(x).Num)
                For y = 0 To Weight(x).Values.GetUpperBound(0)
                    Query += ","
                    Query += CStr(Weight(x).Values(y).TraitName)
                    Query += ","
                    Query += CStr(Weight(x).Values(y).TraitNum)
                    Query += ","
                    Query += CStr(Weight(x).Values(y).WeightValue)
                Next
                Query += ";"
            End If
        Catch
            Query += "FLOCK;"
        End Try
    Next
    Console.WriteLine(Query)
End Sub
```